# Where is the model for non-database functions in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, symfony1

I have used Symfony 1.x forever now and am starting to get a handle on 2.x. What a daunting task converting from 1.x to 2.x is as I'm sure many of you already know.

I have a question about the Model for non database stuff.

in 1.x you had `/lib/model/doctrine/abc.class.php` and `/lib/model/doctrine/abcTable.class.php`. All your non-database model functions went in abc.class.php and all your database stuff went in abcTable.class.php

I want to add a couple of GD functions to make thumbnails of uploaded images but I'm pretty sure in the MVC conventions they are not suppose to go in the controller file. But I can't find a model folder or any place that even says model for non database stuff anywhere in the Symfony2 docs.

Can someone please let me know what the new convention for "Model" for non database elements and custom functions that use to go in lib/model folder are now located (or called) in Symfony2?

Answer (score 0):

There is not really a convention for this type of stuff per say.  You can add the methods to the model, or you can create a separate class that consumes a model and does all of the work that needs to be done.

I personally would create a service that handles the process.  Takes the input from the controller, creates the model and the the thumbnails.  I would not put the gd functions into my model classes.

Comment: ya services seems to be the closest thing to what was happening before. i also have a bunch of other none database functions that don't fit in the controller or database repository. for one function a service makes complete sense. but i have a bunch of functions that are in my old model that i'm not really sure where to put in 2.x